# The control inside of DataGridView tab index order

Tags: c#, winforms

All, I used the below code add a select all check box into DataGridView. So far it works fine. But still have a problem with tab index order. please review it.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[i];


            row.Cells[0].Value = true;
            row.Cells[1].Value = "cell";
            row.Cells[2].Value = "cell"; 
        }
        Rectangle rect =
            this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, -1, true);

        checkBox1.Location = rect.Location;
        checkBox1.Left = 9;
        checkBox1.Top = 3;

        dataGridView1.Controls.Add(checkBox1);
```

My desired tab order setting in the design time is shown below.

[image]

But in the run-time .The tab order is weird. The checkbox tab order is always behind all the cells of the DataGridView. And If the checkbox is not contained in the grid. the order would be fine. it will follow the design order.
Is there any way to fix it ? thanks.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to setup TabIndex property? When you put the controls inside the form their indices are setup by default in order they are placed.

Comment: Hi lale, Did you ever use the `TabOrder` function in the designer? It is located under the menu `View-TabOrder`.And It do the same job of setting TabIndex property with code. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I did. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think order is broken by moving checkBox1 into dataGridView controls collection. You should then handle tabs within that control. It could be done by creating custom DataGridView and overriding ProcessTabKey method [See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737523/how-do-i-change-the-tab-order-in-a-datagridview)