# Setting Tab order in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a datagridview for sales entry where their are itemcode, itemname, barcode ect after typing the item code or itemname or barcode the next tab should go to quantity and then without going to the next coloumn next row should be added

My datagridview image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle it using key press events. You can implement your condition by checking the current cell in datagridview  `dataGridView.CurrentCell`.
see [How do I change the tab order in a DataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737523/how-do-i-change-the-tab-order-in-a-datagridview)